# Twilio Flex AgentDesktopView Panel Sizing

Tags: reactjs, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-flex

For the 2 panels in the AgentDesktopView, I'm trying to adjust the size of Panel 1.

I've tried:

```
flex.AgentDesktopView
   .defaultProps
   .splitterOptions
   .initialFirstPanelSize = '250px'
```

and

```
flex.AgentDesktopView
   .defaultProps
   .splitterOptions
   .minimumFirstPanelSize = '250px'
```

I've tried searching through docs and can't find much information around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you have a plugin you can put the code in, you can try this

```
flex.AgentDesktopView.defaultProps.splitterOptions = {
      initialFirstPanelSize: "250px",
      minimumFirstPanelSize: "250px",
      //minimumSecondPanelSize: "xx%"
    };
```

Either the theme or these component options can be used ie. if you're updating the config in the manager when you changed the options:

```
manager.updateConfig(appConfig);
```

Let me know if this helps at all!